# Integrating Boltzmann distribution with Delta function

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, dirac-delta

Can anyone help me figure out how to find the constant and integrate this distribution function?
$$f(v_x,v_y,v_z) = A \delta(v_z-V_0) e^{-m(v_x^2+v_y^2)/2kT}$$
The integration is because I need to find the flux. I'm not familiar with the delta function.

If I did my work correctly, I would get 
$$n = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f d^3 v = C \cdot2 V_0 \pi  kT /m$$ But again I'm not sure about the delta function and the flux has to be 
$$ =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty f \vec{v} d^3v $$ but I have to find it separately in $x$, $y$ and $z$ directions.

Comment: over which variable do you wanna integrate?

Comment: - \infinity to + \infinity

Comment: hi @tired do you have any hints into going about this problem? thanks

Comment: oops. sorry it is corrected now, but C is something I need to find too @Winther

Comment: First get rid of the delta function by integrating over $v_z$. We have $\int F(v_x,v_y,v_z)\delta(v_z - V)\, dv_xdv_ydv_z = \int F(v_x,v_y,V)\, dv_x dv_y$. Now you are left with two (identical) [gaussian integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) to evaluate.

Comment: Hi @WInther I have done the correction, the v is the vector. and for the first part, does that mean I end up without the V_0 ? thanks

Comment: I fixed some final typos. Check that this is the intended meaning. As for your question: yes there will be no $V_0$ in the integral for $n$. Your $C$ will depend on $A$ and this will allow you to determine $A$ in terms of $n$. To compute the final integral you need to compute the three integrals $\int v_x f {\rm d}^3 v$, $\int v_y f {\rm d}^3 v$ and $\int v_z f {\rm d}^3 v$. The first two integrals will be equal since $v_x$ and $v_y$ are symmetric  in $f$ so you only need to compute one of them.